# Vectorize mask of squared euclidean distance in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, euclidean-distance

I'm running code to generate a mask of locations in B closer than some distance D to locations in A.

```
N = [[0 for j in range(length_B)] for i in range(length_A)]    
dSquared = D*D

for i in range(length_A):
    for j in range(length_B):
        if ((A[j][0]-B[i][0])**2 + (A[j][1]-B[i][1])**2) <= dSquared:
            N[i][j] = 1
```

For lists of A and B that are tens of thousands of locations long, this code takes a while. I'm pretty sure there's a way to vectorize this though to make it run much faster. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `N[j][i] = 1` instead?

Comment: @Divakar – You are correct, I changed the names of items for posting here to make it more simple, and got confused. I have corrected the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scipy's cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) that is supposedly pretty efficient for such distance calculations, like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

N = (cdist(A,B,'sqeuclidean') <= dSquared).astype(int)
```

---

As suggested in [`@hpaulj's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629353/3293881), one can use also use `broadcasting`. Now, from the posted code in the question, it looks like we are dealing with `Nx2` shaped arrays. So, we can basically slice the first and second columns and perform broadcasted subtractions on them separately. The benefit would be that we won't be going `3D` and as such keeping it memory efficient and that might also translate to performance boost. Thus, the squared euclidean distances would be calculated like so -

```
sq_eucl_dist = (A[:,None,0] - B[:,0])**2 + (A[:,None,1] - B[:,1])**2
```

Let's time all these three approaches for squared euclidean distance calculations.

Runtime test -

```
In [75]: # Input arrays
    ...: A = np.random.rand(200,2)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(200,2)
    ...: 

In [76]: %timeit ((A[:,None,:] - B[None,:,:])**2).sum(axis=-1) # @hpaulj's solution
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop

In [77]: %timeit (A[:,None,0] - B[:,0])**2 + (A[:,None,1] - B[:,1])**2
1000 loops, best of 3: 401 µs per loop

In [78]: %timeit cdist(A,B,'sqeuclidean')
1000 loops, best of 3: 249 µs per loop
```

Comment: cdist.asType(bool), in combination with the np.nonzero() on the output resulted in massive performance improvements and memory reductions since the output is quite sparse. Thank you for the help, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to visualize this code with 2d array indexing:

```
for j in range(length_A):
    for i in range(length_B):
        dist = (A[j,0] - B[i,0])**2 + (A[j,1] - B[i,1])**2 
        if dist <= dSquared:
            N[i, j] = 1
```

That `dist` expression looks like

```
((A[j,:] - B[i,:])**2).sum(axis=1)
```

With 2 elements this array expression might not be faster, but it should help us rethink the problem.

We can perform the `i,j`, `outter` problems with broadcasting

```
A[:,None,:] - B[None,:,:]  # 3d difference array

dist=((A[:,None,:] - B[None,:,:])**2).sum(axis=-1)  # (lengthA,lengthB) array
```

Compare this to `dSquared`, and use the resulting boolean array as a mask for setting elements of `N` to 1:

```
N = np.zeros((lengthA,lengthB))
N[dist <= dSquared] = 1
```

I haven't tested this code, so there may be bugs, but I think basic idea is there.  And may be enough of the thought process to let you work out the details for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestions to use Numpy above.  The looping code is also doing a lot more indexing into A than it needs to.  You could use something like:

```
import numpy as np

dimension = 10000
A = np.random.rand(dimension, 2) + 0.0
B = np.random.rand(dimension, 2) + 1.0
N = []
d = 1.0

for i in range(len(A)):
    distances = np.linalg.norm(B - A[i,:], axis=1)
    for j in range(len(distances)):
        if distances[j] <= d:
            N.append((i,j))

print(len(N))
```

It is going to be pretty hard to get decent performance for this out of pure Python.  I would also point out that the more-dimensional array solutions will require a... lot... of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Insofar as your matrix N is likely to be sparse, scipy.spatial.cKDTree will give much better time complexity than any approach based on computing all distances brute force:

```
cKDTree(A).sparse_distance_matrix(cKDTree(B), max_distance=D)
```